# How do I resize a Image inside the ListView control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I'm currently trying to create a collection of image URLS that's then wrapped around a ScrollViewer so I can scroll through them all.

The grid that the collection is in has a GridSplitter so that I can make it wider and it's currently sizing properly, if I make it wider, the images then gets wider.
That's however only if I use the `ItemsControl` and with the `ItemsControl` you can not select an item so I'm stuck with a `ListView` as far as I know and here is where the issue occurs.
When I use the ListView the image doesnt size to fit the width of the ListView and I have to set the width and height properties meaning that they wont move, they'll be static.

Here is the working version, as you can see it fits the images automatically
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VChtK.png)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Url}"
                   Width="Auto"
                   Height="Auto"
                   Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And here is the version that doesnt work, and as you can see it just takes up as much space as it wants [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl9Qx.png)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="{Binding Url}" 
                       Stretch="Fill"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Why does the ListView behave like this whilest the ItemsControl works fine?

Comment: Try to get rid of the `StackPanel` in the `DataTemplate`.

Comment: That didn't seem to do much

Comment: Did you try to use the exact same `DataTemplate`?

Comment: I removed the StackPanel and I tried just using the Image inside the DataTemplate but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Oh.. I forgot about the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` property, and adding that to the ListView fixed it.